# How to loop / repeat the current ringtone in Android from an application?

Tags: android

I am writing an application on android 4.0 which will play the current ringtone when I press a button.

But in the ringtone is played only one time. I need it to repeat for a few times.

My current code:

```
Uri notifi = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(c, notifi);
r.play();
```

Comment: Uri notifi = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
        final Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(c, notifi);
        r.play();

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this code I have used this before and able to play Ringtone continuously until you stop

```
try {
   Uri alert =  RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(this, alert);
  final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
 if (audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING) != 0) {
 mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
 mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
 mMediaPlayer.prepare();
 mMediaPlayer.start();
}
} catch(Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: @satya.I create MediaPlayer in Service class, as I want to use `            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),uri);`, it shows this exception: `Unhandled Exceptiom:java.io.IOException`. how can i solveit?

Comment: @Sam. it's too old! i don't remember why i need it. i will ask you,as i find it.

Comment: Not work with ringtone! : java.io.IOException: setDataSource

Answer (score 9):

Tried the above codes on lollipop and only this worked for me

```
  //activating looping ringtone sound
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
    player = MediaPlayer.create(this, notification);
    player.setLooping(true);
    player.start();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can have a timer regularly check if the ringtone is still playing. For example, every second:

```
mRingtone.play();
mTimer = new Timer();
mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (!mRingtone.isPlaying()) {
            mRingtone.play();
        }
    }
}, 1000*1, 1000*1);
```

Answer (score 2):

I achieved this issues by set looping true with Ringtone and ringtone manager.

```
 Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);

 Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
 r.setLooping(true);
 r.play();
```

Here I am starting ringtone and when we want to stop ringtone we can call

r.stop();

method to stop ringtone

Answer (score 0):

I have read that ringtone has to have `ANDROID_LOOP` tag. Ref: [`http://xanderx.com/2010/08/25/making-ringtones-loop-on-android/`](http://xanderx.com/2010/08/25/making-ringtones-loop-on-android/)

You can also try to play this file using `AudioManager` and set it looping. Ref: [`http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping(boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setLooping%28boolean%29)